# How to do I persists selected value of <li> tag on page refresh through jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html

How Do I maintain the selected value of the ul>li in the below code
HTML Code

```
<ul class="paginationSize">
 <li>SHOW:</li>
 <li id="paginationClass" data-paginationValue="20" class=""><a href="#">20</a>
 </li>
 <li id="paginationClass" data-paginationValue="40" class=""><a href="#">40</a>
 </li>
 <li id="paginationClass" data-paginationValue="60" class=""><a href="#">60</a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

jQuery Related to the PHP CODE

```
$(".paginationSize li").click(function(){
        $(".active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        paginationSize =  $(this).attr("data-paginationValue");
        setGetParameter('pageSize',paginationSize);
    });
```

setGetParameter Function

```
function setGetParameter(paramName, paramValue)
{
    var url = window.location.href;
    var hash = location.hash;
    url = url.replace(hash, '');
    if (url.indexOf(paramName + "=") >= 0)
    {
        var prefix = url.substring(0, url.indexOf(paramName));
        var suffix = url.substring(url.indexOf(paramName));
        suffix = suffix.substring(suffix.indexOf("=") + 1);
        suffix = (suffix.indexOf("&") >= 0) ? suffix.substring(suffix.indexOf("&")) : "";
        url = prefix + paramName + "=" + paramValue + suffix;
    }
    else
    {
    if (url.indexOf("?") < 0)
        url += "?" + paramName + "=" + paramValue;
    else
        url += "&" + paramName + "=" + paramValue;
    }
    console.log(url);
    window.location.href = url + hash;
}
```

I want to maintain the active class on selected option (i.e. If I select option 40 then after page refresh option 40 should be selected and default I have to set active on value 20)

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What code do you refer to?

Comment: So What is code..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/geow8bzu/

```js
if( localStorage.getItem('lastSelectedli') != null ){
   $(".paginationSize li[data-paginationValue=" + localStorage.getItem('lastSelectedli') + "]").addClass('active');
}

$(".paginationSize li").click(function(){
    $(".active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    paginationSize =  $(this).attr("data-paginationValue");
   localStorage.setItem('lastSelectedli', paginationSize);
    //setGetParameter('pageSize',paginationSize);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="paginationSize">
   <li>SHOW:</li>
   <li data-paginationValue="20" class=""><a href="#">20</a>
   </li>
   <li data-paginationValue="40" class=""><a href="#">40</a>
   </li>
   <li data-paginationValue="60" class=""><a href="#">60</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

I've used `localStorage` to store the last selected item.

Remove `id="paginationClass"`, because `id` should be **unique**.

Comment: I copied Your code but still it is not working
I am using jquery-1.4.2.min.js

Comment: @Hetal1311.. What error you are getting in `browser` `console`?

Comment: No error  in console but functionality is not working

Comment: @Hetal1311... There is nothing extra I'm doing, only setting the selected data to `localStorage` for **future reference**.

Comment: your code in jsfiddle link is working fine but yes there is fading in the selected li 

Will it be like that or you have some solution on that

Comment: I didn't get you... If you can post the code in a fiddle, I will definitely help you out.

Comment: I did Code as you Posted on fiddle.
It is Working Fine.
I appreciate your work :)
But While refreshing page, after getting refreshed the selected element got selected in fade manner
Do you have any solution on that ??

Comment: @Hetal1311... Can share your `CSS`? I don't know what you have in the **active** class.

Comment: li.active a{color: #7dbdc2; }

Comment: **Fade** manner is because of the color that you are using, change the color to some dark `li.active a{color: red; }`

Comment: OKay 
Thanks It is Working :)